# Resizing Child View Controllers in UIContainerView swift ios

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout

I am creating an app in which i have to open 2-3 view controller inside a view controller because I want to share same Sliding Drawer and Navigation bar for these view controllers. I have followed [this](https://www.raywenderlich.com/78568/create-slide-out-navigation-panel-swift) tutorial.

I have used **ContainerView** inside **MainController** and child controllers are added properly but I am having difficulty in resizing the child controller to match containerview

```
 self.mainContainer.addSubview(vc.view)
 self.mainContainer.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
 addChildViewController(vc)
 NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
 vc.view.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo:mainContainer.leadingAnchor),
 vc.view.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: mainContainer.trailingAnchor),
 vc.view.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: mainContainer.topAnchor),
 vc.view.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: mainContainer.bottomAnchor)
 ])
vc.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
```

and I am getting the following error

```
[LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
    (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x170095c70 h=-&- v=-&- UIView:0x127e17630.midY == UIView:0x127e15070.midY + 32   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x1740970c0 V:|-(0)-[UIView:0x127e17630]   (active, names: '|':UIView:0x127e15070 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x174097020 UIView:0x127e17630.bottom == UIView:0x127e15070.bottom   (active)>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x174097020 UIView:0x127e17630.bottom == UIView:0x127e15070.bottom   (active)>
```

what I think is **self.mainContainer.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false** is somehow not working
Child View Controllers are not properly getting resized as in the main controller the **navbar is about 64** and the same height of portion is getting clipped in childview controllers from bottom.

**MainController's elements Constraint**

1. navbar left=top=right = 0, height = 64
2. UIContainerView left=right=bottom=0 and top to navbar = 0

Comment: main container constraints 
?

Comment: Sorry i mean its MainController's. Elements that i have placed inside main controller

Comment: should I post a demo code for reference adding constraints programmatically ? you can have a look over it

Comment: try buddy may be I am doing something wrong

Comment: can I get your code file ? or Xcode project ?

Comment: You can download the base project from tutorial link and i will post the code file

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`vc.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false`

Answer (score 11):

Instead of applying constraints to `vc's` `view`, you can simply set the frame of `vc`, i.e.

```
    vc.view.frame = self.containerView.bounds //Here
    self.containerView.addSubview(vc.view)
    self.addChildViewController(vc)
    vc.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
```